# With html_strip as search query analyzer, searches are still performed in HTML markup

Tags: elasticsearch

In short: can `html_strip` be used with analyzer which is used only in queries?

I have a very simple test indice with the following settings:

```
POST test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "synonym": {
          "synonyms_path": "/usr/share/wordnet-prolog/wn_s.pl",
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "type": "synonym",
          "format": "wordnet"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "synonym_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": "html_strip",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "snowball",
            "synonym"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "child": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "parent"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And some sample data:

```
PUT test/parent/1
{
  "type": "flying stuff"
}

PUT test/child/1?parent=1
{
  "name": "butterfly"
}

PUT test/child/2?parent=1
{
  "name": "<strong>tire</strong>"
}
```

On corresponding child/parent searches I get results with the tag name "strong", for example:

```
GET test/parent/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "strong",
            "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET test/child/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "strong",
        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is interesting, when I test tokenizer with `http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?text=%3Cstrong%3Edemo%3C/strong%3E&analyzer=synonym_analyzer&pretty=true` data is interpreted correctly (no "strong" and related synonyms):

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "demonstration",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "demo",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "show",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "exhibit",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "present",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "demonstrate",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I am having same exact problem, Did you find an answer?

Comment: @user1529412 no, unfortunately I haven't had the time to return to this issue.